# Does parent process lose write ability during copy on write?

Tags: operating-system, fork, paging, cpu-architecture, copy-on-write

Say we have a certain parent process with some arbitrary amount of data stored in memory and we use `fork` to spawn a child process. I understand that in order for the OS to perform copy on write, the certain page in memory that contains the data that we are modifying will have its Read-only bit set, and the OS will use the exception that will result when the child tries to modify the data to copy the entire page into another area in memory so that the child gets it's own copy. What I don't understand is, if that specific section in memory is marked as Read-only, then the parent process, to whom the data originally belonged, would not be able to modify the data neither. So how can this whole scheme work? Does the parent lose ownership of its data and copy on write will have to be performed even when the parent itself tries to modify the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, if either process writes a COW page, it triggers a page fault.

In the page fault handler, if the page is *supposed* to be writeable, it allocates a new physical page and does a `memcpy(newpage, shared_page, pagesize)`, then updates the page table of whichever process faulted to map the newpage to that virtual address.  Then returns to user-space for the store instruction to re-run.

This is a win for something like `fork`, because one process typically makes an `execve` system call right away, after touching typically one page (of stack memory).  **`execve` destroys all memory mappings for that process, effectively replacing it with a new process.**  The parent once again has the only copy of every page.  (Except pages that were *already* copy-on-write, e.g. memory allocated with `mmap` is typically COW-mapped to a single physical page of zeros, so reads can hit in L1d cache).

A smart optimization would be for `fork` to actually copy the page containing the top of the stack, but still do lazy COW for all the other pages, on the assumption that the child process will normally `execve` right away and thus drop its references to all the other pages.  It still costs a TLB invalidation in the parent to temporarily flip all the pages to read-only and back, though.

Comment: How will that work if the parent, after modifying some data, decides to spawn a second child? If the parent loses ownership over its data, then there will now be two read-only memory segments. The one after spawning the first child and the second after spawning the second child. And the OS will now have to allocate a third writable segment for the parent to do copy on  write if it decides to modify its data again. This doesn't sound right since it seems like an awful waste of resources.

Comment: @user3769877: as soon as `execve` runs in the child process, all memory mappings are wiped out, so the reference count on all the parent's pages drops back to 1.  (Unless they were already shared).  The child's copy of any pages that COW actually copied are freed on `execve`, whether it was the parent or child that cause the copy to happen.

Comment: But what if exec is never called. That is, we simply call fork once, change some data in parent, then call fork a second a time, change data in parent, call fork a third time... and so on and so forth. How will copy on write work in this case?

Comment: @user3769877: Then all the pages will be shared, except for the few pages that are changed.  Every process that changes a page will have its own copy of that page, like if nothing had ever been shared.  You save a lot of memory compared to copying everything on fork, e.g. if `bash` creates a subshell for a command like `foo; (echo 1234 > file)&  bar`, the subshell that runs `echo > file` doesn't modify most of its pages, so it's worth a few extra pagefaults to avoid a bunch of copying work.  (This was especially true back when Unix was designed, when mem copying was slow compared to pagefault)

Answer (score 0):

> Some UNIX implementations share the ***program text*** between the two since
> that cannot be modified. Alternatively, the child may share all of the
> parent’s memory, but in that case the memory is shared
> **`copy-on-write`**, which means that whenever either of the two wants to modify part of the memory, that chunk of memory is explicitly
> copied first to make sure the modification occurs in a private memory
> area.
>
> Excerpted from: [Modern Operating Systems (4th Edition), Tanenbaum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013359162X)

[image]